# How to uniquily identify selectors?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am performing `[self performSelector:@selector(<selctor>) withObject:<object> afterDelay:30];`

in loop say after every event or action.

if the action fails i want to cancel the perform selector associated with it.

i know about

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self
                                                 selector:@selector(<selector>)
                                                   object:nil]
```

but how to cancel a specific perform selector from say list of all perform selectors called in loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you get some sort of unique reference back (like an object pointer) then you can't uniquely identify each request.

An alternative approach would be to use an `NSTimer` object to invoke the selector, which you can store somewhere and cancel whenever you like via its `invalidate` method.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Just don't use perform selectors. Instead, use `NSOperation` instances added to a queue or add `NSInvocation` instances to a list and execute them when you are sure that all tests are passed.

Comment: Yours seems to be the standard +1 for you but iam using trojanfoe's answer